# why setState doesn't rerender React page

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am having some datas from an API GET call,i store them in datas(so it's not longer a string) and i want to delete some of them when the user choose some filters. I see the data change on the console and setState them but the page doesn't update the new data.

```
const [datas, setData] = useState('');
```

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log("deleting")
    var newdata = datas
    newdata.splice(1, 1);
    console.log(newdata)
    setData(newdata)
};
```

I used a new variable **newdata** because i saw that using the same variable **data** isn't recommended.
`

Comment: You initialize `datas` as a string, and then treat it as an array. Which is it supposed to be?

Comment: I would expect an entirely different error from this code.  Namely: *"Uncaught TypeError: newdata.splice is not a function"*  Since `splice()` is a function on arrays, not strings.

Comment: I then use a GET call and make it an array of objects.

Comment: @kostaskrav: Then why initialize it to a string in the first place?  Keep your data types consistent.  Otherwise you're just asking for bugs and other unexpected behavior, like what you're seeing now.  If `datas` was a string (which *in the code shown* it is) then the error described wouldn't happen, because assigning it by value to another variable would create a new value.  But since *some other code* is modifying the data type and changing it to a reference to an array, that changes the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the content of the array.

Do this in handleClick instead:

```
const handleClick = (event) => {
    console.log("deleting")
    // Create a copy of datas, do not modify the original array
    var newdata = [...datas]
    newdata.splice(1, 1);
    console.log(newdata)
    setData(newdata)
};
```

That would solve it because you're creating **a copy** of the array with the spread operator `...`

As a general rule, I'd always favor **immutable** array methods over **mutable** ones. You can check the docs for the methods and if it reads something like *"changes the contents of an array"*, then the method is mutating the original array. Use methods that return a new copy of the array instead.

Comment: Yes i had to wait 10 minutes because you answered before the threshhold i can accept an answer :P